# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in storyboard loadView after memory warning

Tags: storyboard, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access, loadview

I have created two view controllers say `A` and `B` with storyboard and ARC. VC `A` is calling `B` by `performSegueWithIdentifier` and `B` returns to `A` by `dismissViewControllerAnimated`. This is working well, until I simulate a `Memory Warning` during I am in VC `B`. If I do that, my App is crashing with

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x...)
```

As soon as I execute the `dismissViewControllerAnimated`. For debugging I have added my own `loadView` to `A` (just with a NSLog and `[super loadView]`) and I can see, that it is called and the App is crashing in `[super loadView]`.

I know, that the view hierarchy of `A` was destroyed caused by the memory warning. But as I understand the documentation, it should be automatically recreated when it is accessed after `dismissViewControllerAnimated` of `B`. At time of `loadView` non of my code should run, everything will be initialized in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` and non of them is called before the crash. Does anybody has some suggestions how to further debug, or how to get the identity of the bad address before it becomes bad?

Answer (score 0):

Try using strong in the presentingViewController

for example:

@property (strong, nonatomic) CameraViewController *myCVC;

Answer (score 0):

Have found the problem after rebuilding view controller A object by object. In A I'm using one UIPanGestureRecognizer and one UITapGestureRecognizer. Adding these two objects on the storyboard has also added two lines to viewDidUnload setting the two recognizer to nil when unloading A's view. For ...GestureRecognizer that seems to be a bug. Removing these two lines solved the problem.